# Is there a way to list all resources/components (Models, endpoints, TrainingJobs, etc) associated with a AWS SageMaker Notebook/ Studio Project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker

If I write a script to train and deploy a machine learning model on AWS SageMaker notebook or create a Project using AWS SageMaker Studio, when I try to list all the resources used, using boto3, the information extracted has no pattern linking the resource information to the notebook/project.

[boto3.client('sagemaker').list_models()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5G1B.png)

The boto3 api returns all resource information associated with my account and region. Is there a way to link these info (Models, endpoints, TrainingJobs, ProcessingJobs etc) to the Sagemaker Notebook/ Studio Project they were created in?

Answer (score 1):

When using SageMaker Projects in SageMaker Studio, one of the advantages you get is all the child resources of that Project - models, endpoints, pipelines are tagged with the `project-id`. You can use SageMaker's [search API](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/2.0.33/reference/sagemaker/search.html) with a tag filter to list all resources in SageMaker that are tagged with your project id.